# Angular $http.post and No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, angularjs-service

I have two app with  nodejs and angularjs.nodejs app  has some code like this :

```
require('http').createServer(function(req, res) {


  req.setEncoding('utf8');
  var body = '';
  var result = '';
  req.on('data', function(data) {
      // console.log("ONDATA");

      //var _data = parseInput( data,req.url.toString());
      var _data = parseInputForClient(data, req.url.toString());



      switch (req.url.toString()) {
          case "/cubes":
              {
```

and this app host on `http://localhost:4000`.angularjs app host with node `http-server` module on `localhost://www.localhost:3030`.in one of my angularjs service i have some thing like this :

```
fetch:function(){
         var data = '{somedata:"somedata"}';
        return $http.post('http://localhost:4000/cubes',data).success(function(cubes){
            console.log(cubes);
        });
    }
```

but when this service send a request to server get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:4000/cubes. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3030' is therefore not allowed access.
```

so i search the web and stackoverflow to find some topic and i find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102690/angularjs-not-detecting-access-control-allow-origin-header) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20893854/angular-js-nginx-cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header) . according to these topics i change the header of response in the server to something like this :

```
res.writeHead(200, {
                          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
                      });
                      res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
```

but this dose'nt work.I try with firefox,chrome and also check the request with `Telerik Fiddler Web Debugger` but the server still pending and i get the Access Control Allow Origin error.

Comment: You might need some additional headers, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors-in-express-nodejs  IIRC you need at least the allowed methods one.

Comment: also i fix my problem with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21633218/1262045) answer. the problem is come from post .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do POST request, which generates preflight request according to CORS specification: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Your server should also respond to OPTIONS method (besides POST), and return `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` there too.

You can see it's the cause, because when your code creates request in Network tab (or in Fiddler proxy debugger) you should see OPTIONS request with `ORIGIN` header